flutter-problem with tabbar height in the page
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: tdWhite,
          child: TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            indicatorColor: tdBlack,
            isScrollable: false,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Featured',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp, color: tdBlack),
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'On Sale',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp, color: tdBlack),
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text('Top Rated',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.sp, color: tdBlack)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 500.h,
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: tabViews,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

i want a to make height dynmaic as the stalesswidget height it is impossible?! i try to add expanded and fleixable and i got error. the problem if i put height it is not have same size for all devices . anyone have a solution for this, library,another way without using tabbar to get same design of the tabbar. this is a screenshoot how it look.enter image description here (note that : i am using the tabbar in the middle of the page)
